# How to add an onchange event to all select2s?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using [Select2 3.5.2](http://select2.github.io/select2/) plugin.

I need to add an onchange event to all select2s in my app. I see I can override some defaults via `$.fn.select2.defaults` but I don't see anything in there that would let me set an onChange event. Moreover, my event needs to fire even if another on-change event is bound - it can't unbind the other one.

How can I do this?

Comment: According to the documentation `$("selector")
    .on("change"`

Comment: @mplungjan Yes....but how do I apply that to every input that has a select2 on it, now or in the future?

Comment: @Mark That's how you do, using mplungjan's comment.

Comment: `$("#staticcontainer").on("change",".sel2class", function...`

Comment: @mplungjan (1) select2 doesn't assign a class to your input that I can use to select it, (2) you've ignored the "now or **in the future**" bit. i.e., your code would have to run after every select2 has been instantiated. Some of my pages are dynamic, I can't just put that in the DOM-ready and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
(function() {
    var originalSelect2 = $.fn.select2;

    $.fn.select2 = function() {
        var result = originalSelect2.apply(this, arguments);
        this.on('change', function() {
            // my onchange code here
        });
        return result;
    };

    $.extend($.fn.select2, originalSelect2);
})();
```